# Grabbing RadGridView items with xy index

Tags: c#, wpf

For a normal Datagridview you can get the value of a cell by applying the co-ordinates. 
For example DataGridview[x,y].Value will give back the value at row x, column y. I'm wondering how do I do the same for a RadGridView.

I tried the same annotation but I get the error `Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type 'telerik.windows.Controls.Radgridview]

I also tried `BusinessGrid.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value;`
BUt no luck

Comment: how doesn't `BusinessGrid.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value` work?

Comment: @NETscape - says cannot resolve symbol Rows.